# How I can get one random DateTime from DatePeriod?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm creating one `DatePeriod` with this code:

```
$beginDate=new DateTime();
$beginDate->setTime(0,30);
$mPeriod = new DatePeriod(
    $beginDate, 
    DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 minutes'), 
    90
);
```

I can print each object into this period, for example:

```
foreach ($mPeriod as $period) {
    echo $period->format('Y-m-d H:i') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

But I don't know how I can take only one of the `DateTime` objects into this period. I want use one of these values randomly.

Comment: either put them inside an array, then `array_rand` and get the array using the key returned, or just simply initialize a `random_int` from zero to total count, if *random number* is equal to foreach `key-1`, then echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered with a comment and is therefore always found when searching for unanswered questions.

Variant 2 from Kevin's comment as a code:

```
$beginDate=new DateTime();
$beginDate->setTime(0,30);
$mPeriod = new DatePeriod(
    $beginDate, 
    DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 minutes'), 
    90
);

$rndKey = random_int(0,90);
foreach($mPeriod as $key => $period){
  if($key == $rndKey) {
    echo $period->format('Y-m-d H:i');
  }
}
```

However, if only a random time between 00:30 and 02:00 is required, it is faster and easier without DateInterval:

```
$rndTime = date_create('today 0:30')
  ->modify(random_int(0,90).' Minutes')
;
echo $rndTime->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```